# Run script after web query refresh. Can't get it to work

Tags: microsoft-excel, vbscript

This is the code I have for the worksheet. It works if I type something into D32, but if the formula changes the number automatically it does nothing. What am I doing wrong? I basically have it set to hide a row if a cell is zero or show it if it a positive number.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("D32")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
        ' changed.
        ' Place your code here.
    If Range("D32").Value = "0" Then
        Rows("32:32").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("D32").Value = "<>0" Then
        Rows("32:32").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the Code,,, actually the **Worksheet Change** event check the Value in `D32`, if is `ZERO` the code hides `Row 32` it self and if and in case of other than `Zero` is not getting clicked after been hidden because `D32` is not visible cell to edit.

Comment: **Cont,,,** if you want to get rid from all that,, change the Key Cell D32 to any like `D30` to hide & unhide the `Row 32` !!. And if in `D32` you have entered Formula and you are looking to hide `Row32` if the Formula returns `Zero` then you need to use **Worksheet Calculate Event** but better hide some other Rows instead of Row has Formula,, since after hiding you can't get chance to edit value so that `D32` become `<>0`

Comment: **Cont,,** and your Syntax should `If Range("D32").Value = 0 Then`  and `ElseIf Range("D32").Value <> 0 Then`  ☺

Comment: So I tried: Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
'Updateby Extendoffice
    Dim Xrg As Range
    Set Xrg = Range("K39")
    If Not Intersect(Xrg, Range("K39")) Is Nothing Then
     If Range("K39").Value = 0 Then
        Rows("32:32").EntireRow.Hidden = True
     ElseIf Range("K39").Value <> 0 Then
        Rows("32:32").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    End If
End Sub ...but now it just loops saying calculating and freezes and crashes :(

Comment: @RajeshS Please don't write your answer in multiple comments. Write a real answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Mathew, try this code, is fully functional.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate() 

Dim KeyCells As Range 
Set KeyCells = Range("C1") 

If Range("C1").Value = 0 Then 
Rows("3:5").EntireRow.Hidden = True 

ElseIf Range("C1").Value <> 0 Then 

Rows("3:5").EntireRow.Hidden = False 

End If 

End Sub
```

**N.B.** Adjust Cell/Row references as needed.